# Variable inflation of obstacles in regards to costmap_2d?

Tags: ros

I'm doing a robot navigation and path planning project based on simulating the turtlebot3 and driving with the A* planner.

I'm using a program that allows the robot to plan a route only through 'cells' with no cost value (aka. freespace with an inflation cost of 0). However, adjusting the inflation radius I'm experiencing that the robot either cannot pass through narrow openings when the inflation is higher, but drive along a wall when it is low.

I'm wondering if there is a way to control the inflation or something? My desires outcome is for the robot to drive in the center of wide hallways, not along walls, but be able to pass through doors that it should be able to fit through.

Thank you.

Comment: There is really not a lot to go about from your question. Reading it, it makes sense that the robot struggles in narrow passages when the inflation radius is high and may stick to walls when its low, because what is leading your turtlebot towards the middle when everything else is "free space"? But even despite the costs increase in narrow pathways due to the inflation costs, A* should find at least one path that connects to your goal node as long as the graph is consistent, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem thanks to some advice that made me look outside the box.
The problem was intrinsic to my planner, the fact that allowed space to navigate through was binary (aka. either perfectly allowed to drive through or not allowed).
Instead I changed it so that all space other than the walls were allowed space, and added the cost of a cell (from the cost map) to the cells. That way instead of being binary whether the drive can or can't drive in a cell, both the distance and cost of the cells affect the robots path, making it try to keep away from walls, but able to pass through places of high cost if there's no other way.